# How do I invite a low rep user into chat?

Tags: support, chat

It comes up in chat sometimes, so I figured I'ld post a question and answer on the thing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On the main page go to chat, then site rooms.
[image]
Scroll to the very bottom and create a room.
[image]
Once you're in the room, go to info.
[image]
Then access, and grant explicit write access.
[image]
Then just invite to chat like normal.

Comment: Thank you for posting this and for helping me out with that room, however I just tried it and it doesn't work for me.  I get "Users must have at least 20 reputation to talk" in big red letters.  I wonder if I don't have enough reputation myself to grant write access?

Comment: That's possible I guess.

Comment: you need a specific amount of rep to create a gallery chat room.  if you dont have enough rep you can't give explicit write access.

Comment: I believe they imposed a hard limit on 20 now, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100291/invite-low-rep-users-to-participate-in-chat

Comment: How do you invite the user?