# Requesting chat rights for other users

Tags: discussion, chat, moderation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I invite a low rep user into chat?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3262/how-do-i-invite-a-low-rep-user-into-chat)

Time to time, I get a new user that is committed to their problem, and I would like to help, but the comment lists are getting very long, which StackExchange apparently discourages. I would like to get the user to at least have temporary rights to chat. Is it acceptable to ask a moderator for these things, or should I continue t resolve the problem in comment discussions?