# Could I invite 1 rep users to chat rooms?

Tags: support, chat

I know that users need at least 20 rep to talk in chat. But could I invite them to talk? could I give them a link?

I want to send [this user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/421842/reinstalling-windows-after-a-ubuntu-uninstall) to chat, I vote him up to give him some rep, but still doesn't have 20 rep, how the hell could I send him to chat? :) it's getting toooooo long in comment section.

I flagged the question, I think I should help him cuase it's a severe problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Supposedly** you should be able to invite <20rep users and allow them to chat using this:

> ### Explicit write access add a user
>
> Even when this room is read-only or **their reputation is too low**, these users will be able to talk in this room.

**But that functionality hasn't worked since a good time.**

[image]

Comment: didn't work, it says `user248970 has only 6 reputation, not yet enough to chat`

Comment: See this comment: on the original question @Fischer http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3262/how-do-i-invite-a-low-rep-user-into-chat#comment4663_3263

Comment: Ok, i need a gallery room? I can  create that

Comment: That feature is mod only. Relevant feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100291/invite-low-rep-users-to-participate-in-chat

Comment: @wilf Emma,  create what?

Comment: @Seth - Errrr... - Create low rep chat rooms for low-rep users, and then if they start spamming or something silly, have it closed?

Comment: @Wilf Yes they could do that, you'd just have to find  a mod to set it up for you.  (note, I have no idea how that "a" got into my last comment my mobile keyboard must have corrected "emm" to "emma")

Comment: The wonders of auto-completion....